# How to prevent program from deleting last index in method

Tags: java, arrays, indexing, return

I have created a method that will take the first two values of the previous array and add them together and repeating this until it has created a new array of the added values. However, what I want to add a rule where if the last number of the previous array is odd I don't want that number to be added. I was able to somewhat do this but unfortunately at the cost of deleting the 2nd to last value of the index. Example my array of {1, 4, 6, 8, 3, 4, 6, 7, 10, 1} is printing [5,14,7,13,1] while I got the last number I still want that 10 to exist but I am stumped on how to get the code to work while not erasing the 10.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class reduceNumbers{
     public static int[] reduce(int[] numArray){
         int[] returnedArray = new int[(numArray.length) / 2]; 
         if(returnedArray[returnedArray.length - 1] % 2 == 1){
         for(int i = 0; i < returnedArray.length; i++) { 


         returnedArray[i] = numArray[2 * i] + numArray[2 * i + 1]; 
    }

}
else{
  for(int i = 0; i < returnedArray.length - 1; i++) { 


    returnedArray[i] = numArray[2 * i] + numArray[2 * i + 1]; 
}

returnedArray[returnedArray.length - 1] = numArray[numArray.length - 1];


}



return returnedArray;
}     

public static void main(String[] args){

int[] firstArray = {1, 4, 6, 8, 3, 4, 6, 7, 10, 1};

   int[] firstArrayA, 

   firstArrayA= reduce(firstArray);


       System.out.println(Arrays.toString(firstArrayA) );


   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

is this what you wanted?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class reduceNumbers{
    public static int[] reduce(int[] numArray){
        boolean even = numArray.length % 2 == 0;
        if(even) {
            int[] returnedArray = new int[numArray.length / 2];
            for(int i=0;i<returnedArray.length;i++) {
                returnedArray[i] = numArray[i * 2]  + numArray[i * 2 + 1];
            }
            return returnedArray;
        }
        else{
            int[] returnedArray = new int[(numArray.length + 1) / 2];
            for(int i = 0; i < returnedArray.length - 1; i++) {
                returnedArray[i] = numArray[i * 2] + numArray[i * 2 + 1];
            }
            returnedArray[returnedArray.length - 1] = numArray[numArray.length - 1];
            return returnedArray;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] firstArray = {1, 4, 6, 8, 3, 4, 6, 7, 10, 1};
        int[] firstArrayA = reduce(firstArray);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(firstArrayA) );
    }
}
```

I refactored your code by only allocating your returnedArray for each case instead of allocating it before you check the parity.

Answer (score 0):

To address the reason why your last element is a 1 the snippet of code:

```
returnedArray[returnedArray.length - 1] = numArray[numArray.length - 1];
```

should be instead:

```
returnedArray[returnedArray.length - 1] = numArray[numArray.length - 1] + numArray[numArray.length - 2];
```

in your else statement!

overall your code should look like this:

```
import java.io.*;

public class StackOverflow {
    public static int[] reduce(int[] numArray) {
        int[] returnedArray = new int[(numArray.length) / 2];
        if (returnedArray[returnedArray.length - 1] % 2 == 1) {
            for (int i = 0; i < returnedArray.length; i++) {

                returnedArray[i] = numArray[2 * i] + numArray[2 * i + 1];
            }

        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < returnedArray.length - 1; i++) {

                returnedArray[i] = numArray[2 * i] + numArray[2 * i + 1];
            }

            returnedArray[returnedArray.length - 1] = numArray[numArray.length - 1] + numArray[numArray.length - 2];

        }

        return returnedArray;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] firstArray = { 1, 4, 6, 8, 3, 4, 6, 7, 10,1 };

        int[] firstArrayA;

        firstArrayA = reduce(firstArray);

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(firstArrayA));

    }
}
```

Comment: The thing that I want to do is to be able to use the for loop to add together the first few values but I don't want it to add the last value if it is odd. By doing that I am adding together last value returning an 11 when what i want is a 10, 1.

Comment: I just updated your code give that a look, i didnt realize your if statement was to check for  even/odd! I do recommend looking at Simons answer as it seems to check in a clearer fashion.